# Websocket connection failed when I added Authorize attribute to the hub

Tags: c#, blazor, signalr, blazor-webassembly

So I am encountering this weird behavior with my blazor app when connecting to websocket. When I added Authorize attribute at the top of the hub, my application doesn't want to connect to the wss. However, when I tried sending a request, it still works as expected (I am guessing its doing it over http?). Also, when I checked my network tab, it doesn't say 401 error or anything, the status of it just says finished. What did I do wrong here?

This is the error message I got
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLyZM.png

And this is the screenshot of my network tab
https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5c3v.png

And this is how I currently implement my hub

```
using Duende.IdentityServer.Extensions;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using System.Security.Claims;

namespace BagiBagiDev.Server.Hubs
{
    [Authorize]
    public class PaymentHub : Hub
    {
        public async Task TestMessage(string user, string message)
        {
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
        }
        public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {
            var username = Context.User.FindFirst(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Name).Value;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
            {
                await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, username);
            }
            await base.OnConnectedAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried searching on the internet and a lot of people were pointing to a vscode bug, but I think that should've been fixed with the current version that I have (v 17.6) so I am not sure what's going on.

Comment: https://github.com/BrianLParker/BlazorSelfHostedAuthWithSignalr/tree/master/BlazorSelfHostedAuthWithSignalr

Comment: I was alluding to this yesterday look at the middleware on the server project

Comment: Hey @BrianParker, sorry I didn't see your comment earlier on the other question. I compared your middleware and mine and looks like I'm missing the middleware to check for the bearer token. I added it and it works like a charm. Thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All credits goes to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1492496/brian-parker) guy right here!

Turns out I miss a middleware to check for when the accessToken was received in the middleware.

```
builder.Services.TryAddEnumerable(
            descriptor: ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<
                IPostConfigureOptions<JwtBearerOptions>,
                ConfigureJwtBearerOptions>());
```

Now it works like a charm. Thanks again for all your help Brian!